# Set up Selenium2 Mink extension on Behat to use more than one browser

Tags: grid, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I'd like to run my behat tests on several browsers using my selenium2 grid. I've managed to make them run on a per-environment/browser basis with different behat.yml config files, but I'd like to have one single behat config file configured to trigger runs on all of my nodes.

My behat.yml config file looks like this:

`default:
    ...
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base-url: http://www.myapp.com
            javascript_session: selenium2
            selenium2:
                browser: 'firefox'
                wd_host: selenium2:4444/wd/hub
    ...`

What I've already tried without luck:

- Array in the browser field `browser: {firefox, chrome}`, config parser doesn't like it
- String with more than one name `browser: 'firefox, chrome'`, thinks i have a browser named after the string *sigh*
- Giving one single name to my selenium nodes, something general like `browser`, for some reason tries to use the iexplorer node (what?!)
- Leaving browser field empty `browser: ''`, triggers only firefox node as seems to be the default one
- I've even tried creating more than one `browser` key in the yaml file, last entry overrides the rest

As mentioned above, it seems the only way of achieving this is by creating a behat.yml file on a per-environment basis, ie. behat-firefox.yml, behat-chrome.yml, and run them in parallel. Something like this (http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/)

Any other suggestions?

**Update**

The version of my tools:

- Behat 2.5.3
- Mink 1.5

Answer (score 5):

I've done a cross-browser implementation and the solution i've found is using Ant, like below

**Behat.yml**

Create a separate profile for each browser as we have created in behat.yml as shown below

```
chrome:
  context:
    class:  'FeatureContext'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base-url: http://www.myapp.com
      javascript_session:  'selenium'
      browser_name: googlechrome
      goutte:              ~
      selenium:

safari:
  context:
    class:  'FeatureContext'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base-url: http://www.myapp.com
      javascript_session:  'selenium2'
      browser_name: safari
      goutte:              ~
      selenium2:

firefox:
  context:
    class:  'FeatureContext'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base-url: http://www.myapp.com
      javascript_session:  'selenium2'
      browser_name: firefox
      goutte:              ~
      selenium2:
```

**Build.xml**

This is a main config where we are creating separate targets for the each profile also generating nice looking html reports for each browsers. Try to understand config below

```
<project name="behat" basedir=".">
   <target name="run">
    <delete dir="${basedir}/report" />
      <mkdir dir="${basedir}/report"/>
      <parallel>
      <antcall target="chrome"></antcall>
      <antcall target="safari"></antcall>
       <antcall target="firefox"></antcall>
     </parallel>
  </target>
  <target name="chrome">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="php" failonerror="true">
    <arg line= "bin/behat -f html --out report/chrome.html -p chrome"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="safari">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="php" failonerror="true">
    <arg line= "bin/behat -f html --out report/safari.html -p safari"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="firefox">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="php" failonerror="true">
    <arg line= "bin/behat -f html --out report/firefox.html -p firefox"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Don’t forget to start selenium-server before running tests. You should run following commands..

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar
```

Once you done with config, you need to run ANT with main target called `run`

```
ant run
```

The source of this tutorial is [here](http://shashikantjagtap.net/running-cross-browser-bdd-scenarios-in-parallel-with-ant/)

Comment: I'm currently using behat profiles to separate product features in our tests:  

    default:
        ...
        extensions:
            <same as above>
        ...
    feature1:
        filters:
            tags: "@feature1"
    feature2:
        filters:
            tags: "@feature2"

The reason for this is to allow us to run several feature tests in parallel using [ParallelRunner][1] Behat's extension. Do you think both things can work together?.

Cheers,

[1]:https://github.com/shvetsgroup/ParallelRunner

Comment: @manei_cc well, really, i don't know, you need to try it. 
I have success using ant to run cross-browser at same feature, using [Feature Context](http://docs.behat.org/guides/4.context.html) when i call the SuperContext, all features - more or less 30 - run sequentially, one after another.

Comment: For the record, I've managed to make those selenium nodes run in parallel using "GNU parallel (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)", taking Jakub Salas (http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/) post and @thiago-franca collaboration for the idea. The problem with this approach is that I still have to create several behat.yml files based on the browser I want to test against, then I can call behat ( using `--config` option) as stated in Zalas post. In case anyone lands here there's also a related question in Behat's google group: http://bit.ly/R4iejc

Comment: @manei_cc That's nice... I will following the group to see your evolution and help when it is possible.